# Clean checkout from TFS 2008

Tags: tfs, visual-studio-2008, version-control, vcs-checkout

I want to pass a project to a colleague without SCC bindings to avoid accidental changes in my repository.

Is it possible to do a clean checkout from a TFS 2008 repo? I'm going crazy finding such an option in VS2008.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think this is possible. As far as I know TFS does not contain an export like functionality as SVN does.

You can do a hard "unbind" However as:

File -> Source Control -> Change Source Control and then unbind and/or disconnect all projects and the solution.

But watch out this will remove the bindings from the solution and project files.

Comment: We're doing this right now. Well, not the optimal way, but it works.

Thanks to all :)

Answer (score 0):

Rody has a good answer, but here is another hack way to do it.

If you delete all the .vspscc files and then reload the solution it should prompt you saying that it cannot find all the source control information, and one of the options from that is to work disconnected.

Comment: I've done that in the past with SourceSafe (ok, it's not the same thing, but not so different so far) and was a PIA :(